# Gremlin: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server

Tags: docker, graph, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I'm using a Docker instance for my janusGraph database and being very specific; I use the following Docker image:
https://github.com/sunsided/janusgraph-docker

The image works OK, except as soon as I get rid of row number 12 in this groovy file: https://github.com/sunsided/janusgraph-docker/blob/master/janusgraph/empty-sample.groovy which contains the following:

```
graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('data/air-routes-small.graphml')
```

If I try to select any vertices from the database using gremlin python, after removing the previously mentioned line, I get the following error:

```
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 499: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.
```

So without importing any existing data, it doesn't work. But I would like to start with an empty database, not an existing one, which is the reason I don't want to import a .graphml file. But I guess I still need to initialize an empty database somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, it seems that `def addItUp(x, y) { x + y }` was missing at the top of the groovy file. I replaced all code with the groovy sample file from the `gremlin-server/scripts` folder, which worked for me.